# WordPress Gutenberg editor changes my manually added HTML and thus destroys a WP Featherlight gallery feature

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, featherlight

On a page that shows a series of images (not a gallery) I did add the [WP Featherlight plugin](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#featherlight-gallery). Then I opened the page with this series of images in Gutenberg's code viw. As described [in the docs](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#usage), I added a link around every `<img>` tag and included the attribute `data-featherlight="#mycustomgallery"`.
After saving the page, the source code view in the browser shows that this attribute was changed to `data-featherlight="image"`. I don't like when an editor changes my manual additions without a warning.

Does someone has an idea how I could keep the attribute `data-featherlight="#mycustomgallery"` in Gutenberg's code view?

Or, I can also change my question to:
How can we show a a series of pictures as a featherlight lightbox that allows to user to watch the images also as a series of images in the same lightbox, and nt only every single image in that page?

Comment: Are you using the HTML Block? I would suggest if you are happy coding you could use shortcodes to make sure your code is not changed. Otherwise you can look here ( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_allowed_html/ ) to adjust what html tags and attributes you would like to allow.